# Can a SSIS variable have a SSIS expression as its value?

Tags: variables, ssis, expressionbuilder

I have a variable "variable1" defined with SSIS expression as its value. Is there a way to evaluate the "variable1" as expression in a second variable "variable2"?

For example,
variable1 is as below:
[image]

When I evaluate variable2 by adding the variable1 in the expression builder, I see the same value of variable1.
[image]

Is there a way to get the variable2 to evaluate the expression "YEAR(GETDATE())" and give the result (2022) as its value?

Answer (score 0):

Because `YEAR(GETDATE())` is being saved as a string value directly inside of User::variable1, the expression builder does not recognize that you are trying to obtain the evaluation of this statement; it thinks you are wanting it to be passed directly as a string.

`YEAR(GETDATE())` would first need to be used in the expression field for User::variable1, and once it is updated there you should see the expected result when using @[User::variable1].

However, one problem remains--because User::variable1 is a string and the [YEAR() function returns an integer value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), you would first need to convert the result from an integer to a string. You could do this by setting this value into the expression field for User::variable1:

```
(DT_WSTR, 5) YEAR(GETDATE())
```